# "MessageBodyReader not found" after working fine

Tags: android, jersey, jersey-client

So, we're working on an Android application.  Among our gradle imports are the following:

```
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.25'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.8.3'
```

We use these to call REST endpoints on one of our servers.  For example:

```
enterSpaceTarget.path(Long.toString(skId)).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();
```

or

```
Form form = new Form();
form = form.param("username", username);
form = form.param("password", password);
form = form.param("rememberMe", Boolean.toString(true));
loginWebTarget.request().post(Entity.form(form), String.class);
```

or

```
long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
Long server = pingTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(Long.class);
long after = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

I'll use the last one as an example as we continue.  See, it works great...for about 45 minutes.  It's difficult to run many tests at this time scale, but everything works fine when you first start up the app, and for hours if you keep pushing buttons, but after about 45 minutes of no web client calls being made, the next call to be made fails.  In the first example, it fails silently, throwing no exception, but in the third example, it throws a MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException, as follows:

```
javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/html, type=class java.lang.Long, genericType=class java.lang.Long.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:811)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$700(JerseyInvocation.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:701)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:697)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:420)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:316)
    at com.....RestClient.ping(RestClient.java:126)
    at com.....VPBCommunicator.lambda$new$3$VPBCommunicator(VPBCommunicator.java:196)
    at com.....VPBCommunicator$$Lambda$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/html, type=class java.lang.Long, genericType=class java.lang.Long.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1085)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:874)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:808)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:806)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

I strongly suspect that this is just a manifestation of a deeper problem - as I said, some of the other calls just fail silently.  Does anybody know why this might be happening, and how to fix it?

Comment: You're getting an error on the server, that's why you're getting html back `MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/html`. Check the server log, check the body of the request. Also it's always a good idea to check the status code before trying to deserialize on the client side, that way you can handle error cases correctly, instead of just failing the deserizliation and getting the exception you are currently getting

Comment: @peeskillet Well heck, for a minute I thought you were crazy, but turns out you were right.  That was apparently long enough for our server to log you out, and the auto-login procedure isn't working right.  (We'll also have to change the status code on redirect....)  Thanks!  ...What do I do about accepting an answer?  Do you want to turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/html

Unless text/html is the type that you requested, almost all the time this means that there is an error on the server side, and what you are getting the server error page. You should check you server logs to see what the problem is.

As an aside, it is always a good idea to first check the status of the response to that you can handle the error properly, instead of automatically trying to deserialize an error response and end up getting the exception you are currently getting

```
Response response = target().request().get();
if (isError(response)) {
   handleError(response);
} else {
   Long result = response.readEntity(Long.class);
}
```